# How to change a particular style in a angular component which has a selector of another component

Tags: angular

I have 5 component all have the same footer

```
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

In the footer component there is a line of code

```
footer {
margin-top: 80px;
}
```

In all the 4 components this works fine. But in the 5th component where I am using the footer `<app-footer></app-footer>` I dont need the margin top.

So in the 5th component I tried

```
footer { margin-top: 0 !important }
```

and

```
<app-footer style="margin-top: 0"></app-footer>
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: use class instead of style if you want to use <app-footer style="margin-top: 0"></app-footer> then the correct code would be <app-footer style="margin-top: 0 !important;"></app-footer>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use :host pseudo-class,

**Try this:**

**footer.component.css**

```
:host(.withoutpadding) .footer{
 color:red;
 padding: 0px;
}

.footer{
  padding: 10px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-footer class="withoutpadding"></app-footer>
<app-footer ></app-footer>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-di7spx)

[ForMoreInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host())

Answer (score 0):

Adding `style="margin-top: 0;"` will not work because you are giving the `app-footer` component a `margin-top` class while the `footer` tag within the component will still contain the `margin-top: 80px;` style. You can pass a check to the `app-footer` component and conditionally add the `margin-top: 80px;` style

**parent component**

```html
<app-footer [showMargin]="true"></app-footer>
```

**app-footer.component.ts**

```js
@Input showMargin: boolean;
```

**app.footer.component.html**

```html
<footer [ngClass]="{'margin-top': showMargin}">
    // ...
</footer>
```

**app.component.css**

```css
.margin-top {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<hello [ngStyle]="{overflow: 'scroll', color:'red',margin:80 +'px'}"></hello>
```